# Resolve masked/shortened URL twint is scraping from twitter

Tags: python, redirect, web-scraping, twitter, twint

I am using `twint` for scraping twitter profiles.

When I run this script:

```
    c = twint.Config()
    c.Username = username
    c.Store_object = True
    c.Store_object_users_list = users
    c.Hide_output = True
    twint.run.Lookup(c)
    try:
        userna = users[0]
    except:
        continue
    web = userna.url
```

I get the masked/shortened URL instead of a real one. How can I get the real url?

What would you advise?

Answer (score 3):

<sub>**Preface:** This answer is based on my results and findings from evaluating [UVuuMe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65833602/2932052) (in it's initial version).</sub>

---

To translate a shortened URL into the full URL it represents, you can use the package  [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) which comes indirectly with `twint` (it's required by `googletransx` which is required by `twint` which you already installed, so there is *no need for `pip install requests`*).

[Send a HEAD request](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.head), then check the response's `status_code` for [`303`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303), only then read the `location` header; there are other cases where a `location` will be in the response, but not in case of *`HTTP 200 OK`.*

```py
import requests

# Short URL for a Python Requests Tutorial
short_url = 'https://youtu.be/tb8gHvYlCFs'

res = requests.head(short_url)
if res.status_code == 303: # "See Other"
    full_url = res.headers['location']
elif res.status_code == 200: # "OK"
    # let's conclude that short_url is already what we are looking for
    full_url = short_url
else:
    # replace by your error handling:
    assert(False)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works.

```
import requests


resp = requests.head(short_link)
resp.status_code
true_url = resp.headers["Location"]
```

Comment: I added a small fix, hopefully this is okay with you.